# How to convert ctypes to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to access ctype.Structure with I have defined, as a bytes in Python (`b''`).

I don't know it is a correct way? I need to send a header (it should be architecture free) to other device.

So I defined it for example as:

```
    class Header(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 2
    _fields_ = [
        ('version', c_uint8),
        ('additional_options', c_uint8),
        ('soft_version', c_uint16),
        ('compilation_time', c_uint8 * 6),
        ('crc', c_uint16)
    ]
```

Now I need to calculate CRC. Start from filed at `version` to `compilation_time` I have a function that work with bytes.

So for me it would be OK just convert ctypes.Structure to bytes (b'') or access directly memory and change last two bytes.

*I have tried use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) but I didn't found **pragma** option.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct` is what you want:

```
>>> import struct
>>> fmt = struct.Struct('<BBH6s')
>>> data = fmt.pack(1,2,3,b'170207')
>>> data
b'\x01\x02\x03\x00170207'
>>> crc = <do your calculation>
>>> data += struct.pack('<H',crc)
```

`<` means pack little-endian and will not add padding bytes like C would, so no `_pack_` is necessary.  If you need big-endian, use `>` instead.

I used `6s` and passed a byte string of the correct length for your time.  If you want to pass raw bytes instead use `6B` and list the 6 bytes instead of the one string.

Here's a ctypes solution.  I used crc32 because one was available in the library for demo purposes.

```
from ctypes import *
from binascii import crc32

class Header(Structure):
    _pack_ = 2
    _fields_ = [
        ('version', c_uint8),
        ('additional_options', c_uint8),
        ('soft_version', c_uint16),
        ('compilation_time', c_uint8 * 6),
        ('crc', c_uint32)
    ]

h = Header(1,2,3)
h.compilation_time = (c_uint8 * 6)(*b'ABCDEF') 
b = bytes(h)[:Header.crc.offset] # convert struct to bytes and truncate CRC
print(b)
h.crc = crc32(b) # Set the correct CRC
b = bytes(h)     # convert whole struct to bytes
print(b)
```

Output:

```
b'\x01\x02\x03\x00ABCDEF'
b'\x01\x02\x03\x00ABCDEF\xe7s\x85\xa6'
```

Comment: BIG disadvantage of this solution is readability. My header is 128bytes long so it will be really messed and unreadable (compare to ctypes). 

Second what with machines where `H` = `unsigned short` **!=** 16-bits?

Comment: @S.R You mentioned "tried use struct but I didn't found **pragma** option".  Be more specific if you don't want struct used at all.  Anyway, updated to show a ctypes solution.

Comment: @MarekTolonen in my opinion both option aren't as readable as rest of python codes. But I finally used native `struct`.